Backup Firestore not working with Github Actions Error 127
I have been using Github actions to backup firestore for the past year with no issues on a cron job that runs everyday but it recently started giving me an error. An error i don't understand.
name: Backup Firestore with SA Key

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "0 02 * * *"

env:
  PROJECT_ID: myproject-v1
  BUCKET: gs://firestore-myproject

jobs:
  backup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@main
      - id: auth
        name: Authenticate with Google Cloud
        uses: google-github-actions/auth@v1
        with:
          credentials_json: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY }}
          export_default_credentials: true
      - run: gcloud info
      - run: gcloud config set project $PROJECT_ID
      - run: gcloud firestore export $BUCKET


The error message that I get is:

/home/runner/work/_temp/ee529994-6691-498a-999d-f0fe733a5d11.sh: line
1: gcloud: command not found Error: Process completed with exit code
127.

